# Insert form and multiple upload

Tags: php, html, mysql, upload

I want to insert an advertisement. The advertisement contains a title, some text, a price and can have one or multiple images. The form is all on one page. So is the php and the html in one file.

In my database I have an `advertisement` table and an `image` table. they both have a unique id as primary.

The `image` table also contains a `filename` and an `advertisement_id` from the `advertisement table` that is the foreign key to that table.

Questions:

1. How do I upload multiples files?
2. Do I need to insert everthing at once or do I insert the advertisement first and then the pictures?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="image"  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="filename[]" id="filename" multiple">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your second question, I thing it would be more sensible to insert the advertisement then insert all the pictures.

For your first question,

The html code would be something like that

```
    <form name="multiupload" action="uploadmany.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="filesToUpload[]" type="file" multiple /></td>
    <td collapse=2><input name="savemultiimg" type="submit" value="submit"></td>
    </form>
```

and here is the php code. the variable `$err` is the notification of the uploading state.

```
    <?php
require("DataBaseConnection.php");
if(isset($_POST["savemultiimg"])) {
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name']);$i++){
        $name=$_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'][$i];
        $tmp_name=$_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i];


$target_dir = "images/";  //the dir where you want to save images
$target_file = $target_dir . rand().'_'.($name); //this will be the name of the img, and we will give it a random number so if you uploaded two image with same name you don't have a problem
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    $check = getimagesize($tmp_name);
    if($check !== false) {
        //echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $err= "file you uploaded is not an image";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }//end if

// Check if file already exists,, this will appear if you removed the random number on the top
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $err ="file already exists";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}//end if

if ($uploadOk != 0)
{
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_file)) {
    $err ="file uploaded succ.";
    $sql = "...";//your sql here
    $result = $con->query($sql);

} else {
    $err ="unecpected error occured";
}   //end if upload

    }//end ($uploadOk != 0)
}//end forloop
header('Location: index.php?err='.$err.');
}
?>
```

This code is from one of my university projects, and I have just modified it to suet you. if it caused you any error just tell me and I'll be happy to help you.

The origin code is copied from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) ,and the changes were made for the multiple upload.

Comment: Im gonna try it now, ill let you know the results!

Comment: i cant check if its working. the page does not show anything with the code implemented in the page.

Comment: after a few changes due to my mistakes it works great! I only need a multiple selecter.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-html5-file-upload.html)?

Comment: Yes, but i tried a few of them and i cant get them installed properly :(

Comment: and my question is then when i want to upload the files how do i do that with the AJAX mini uploader.

Comment: the [first](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/) `AJAX mini uploader` in the link in my previous comment is easy to install, but if you want to use it or any other  `AJAX mini uploader`, you can't use my code, or at least the first lines in my code. This is because the first lines in my code uploads from standard `HTML input`. as for the rest of my code parts (checking the size, name..etc) you can use them :)